# How do I use an if statment to check if a string literal is a certain word or phrase

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I am still new to coding and was playing around trying to figure out simple conversations and I get the following errors while compiling:

> error: could not convert 'str.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=, std::allocator >(((const char*)"good"))' from 'std::basic_string' to 'bool'
>     if (str = "good") {

and

> error: could not convert 'str.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=, std::allocator >(((const char*)"bad"))' from 'std::basic_string' to 'bool'
>     else if (str = "bad") {

I get those errors from the following code. Bear in mind I'm still very new to this:

```
// random practice on conversation
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str;
    string bad;

    cout << "How has your day been?  \n";
    cin >> str;
    if (str = "good") {
        cout << "Thats good to hear!\n";
    }
    else if (str = "bad") {
        cout << "That's too bad, what happened?  \n";
        cin >> bad;
        cout << "I'm sorry to hear that...\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "I'm sorry, I couldn't understand you...\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: equality in c++ uses `==`, not `=`.

Comment: and that solved it, that made me feel even more beginnner, thank you for the help.  I both can't and can believe that was the only problem... oh well, still so much more to learn

Comment: Did your compiler really not give you a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90b567a3c765f0c7) about = vs. ==?

Comment: what i posted was the only two errors i got, im using the compiler DEV-C++ 5.10

Answer (score 4):

= is not the comparison operator, it's the assignment operator. == is the comparison operator.

```
if( str == "bad" )
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(str == "good"){


}
```

You need the double equals sign, otherwise you are setting the string variable `str` to be `"good"` or `"bad"` instead of checking if it equals that.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ the == operator does not work for string. If you want to compare two strings s1 and s2, either use s1.compare(s2) or other variants of the function. You can also use strncmp() function for this purpose.